# find special cases while comparing files in reverse order

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BS 12

void reverse(char * buffer, int size)
{
  char tmp;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
  {
    tmp = (char)buffer[i];
    buffer[i] = buffer[size - i - 1];
    buffer[size - i - 1] = tmp;
  }
}

int compare_bin(char * buffer, char * buffer2, int size)
{
  // because strncmp is only for string without \x00, so there must be a customized compare function
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if(buffer[i] != buffer2[i])
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main (const int argc, const char** argv)
{
  if(argc != 3)
    exit(-1);

  int equal = 1;
  char * buffer = malloc(BS), * buffer2 = malloc(BS);
  FILE * f1, * f2;
  f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  f2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

  fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END);
  fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_END);

  long i = ftell(f1), j = ftell(f2);
  if(i != j)
  {
    equal = 0;
    goto endp;
  }

  fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_SET);

  int need = 0;
  int count;
  int f2_pos = 0;

  do
  {
    i = i - BS;
    if(i < 0)
    {
      need = BS - abs((int)i);
      i = 0;
    }
    else
      need = BS;

    fseek(f1, i, SEEK_SET);
    count = fread(buffer, need, 1, f1);

    reverse(buffer, count * need);
    // fwrite(buffer, count * need, 1, f2);
    fread(buffer2, need * need, 1, f2);

    // printf("compare...\n");
    // for(int i = 0; i < need * count; i++)
    // {
    //   printf("%02hhX", buffer[i]);
    // }
    // printf("\n");
    // for (int i = 0; i < need * count; i++)
    // {
    //   printf("%02hhX", buffer2[i]);
    // }
    // printf("\n");


    if(compare_bin(buffer, buffer2, need * count) == 0)
    {
      equal = 0;
      break;
    }

    f2_pos += need * count;
    fseek(f2, f2_pos, SEEK_SET);

    if(i == 0)
      break;
  }while(i > 0);

  fclose(f1);
  fclose(f2);
  free(buffer);
  free(buffer2);

  endp:
  if(equal)
    return 0;
  else
  {
    printf("2 files not equal is reversed order\n");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So I write a program to compare file content in reverse order. I have already considered `\x00` in binary file and `strncmp` isn't used. But there is still flaw. There is a test server to test this program. But I dont have access to it. This program always fails on that server. So there must be some special cases to make it fail. Any idea?

There are other ways around it. For instance, calculating MD5. But I want to fix this.

Comment: if you deal with binary files, don't use `"r"` mode but `"rb"` mode to open files.

Comment: Jack, you have asked variations of this question several times now. May I suggest before you go any further, you read the man pages for `fread` and the similar `fwrite`, as you have previously been advised that the `size` and `count` arguments are the other way round? And after several posts, you still have a "naive typing error?"

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry. I have been programming all day long. I am very tired and made naive mistakes. Honestly, that is typing error. If that guy cancels his answer, I am willing to delete this post.

Comment: I hope "that guy" has made a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the very first iteration where you read data you have

```
fread(buffer2, need * need, 1, f2);
```

The problem is that in that case `need` is `12`, which is the size of the memory allocated for `buffer2`, but you ask to read `12 * 12` bytes.

If the second file is large enough, you will write out of bounds in the memory, leading to *undefined behavior*. If the file is *not* large enough then you won't read anything.

Also note that the order of the two middle arguments to [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) matter. If you changed the order you would write out of bounds of the buffer both if the file is larger than `need * need` or not. You should really read `count` byte-sized object (the second argument should be `1` and the third should be `count`, which of course mean you need to change the order in the first call as well).

In short, your two `fread` calls should be

```
count = fread(buffer, 1, BS, f1);
fread(buffer2, 1, count, f2);
```

PS. Don't forget error checking.